# What does <false> mean? in “class ScopedBytesRW : public ScopedBytes<false>”

Tags: c++, class, java-native-interface

What does `<false>` and `<true>` mean in the following code?

I analyzed the JNI implementation of the file read and write of the Android system, and found the following C++ code.

I don't know in "class ScopedBytesRO: public ScopedBytes", what is the meaning of `<true>`

Who can help me？

Thanks！

android-6.0.1-2.1.0\libnativehelper\include\nativehelper\ScopedBytes.h

```
#ifndef SCOPED_BYTES_H_included
#define SCOPED_BYTES_H_included
#include "JNIHelp.h"

template<bool readOnly>
class ScopedBytes {
public:
    ScopedBytes(JNIEnv* env, jobject object)
    : mEnv(env), mObject(object), mByteArray(NULL), mPtr(NULL)
    {
        if (mObject == NULL) {
            jniThrowNullPointerException(mEnv, NULL);
        } else if (mEnv->IsInstanceOf(mObject, JniConstants::byteArrayClass)) {
            mByteArray = reinterpret_cast<jbyteArray>(mObject);
            mPtr = mEnv->GetByteArrayElements(mByteArray, NULL);
        } else {
            mPtr = reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(mEnv->GetDirectBufferAddress(mObject));
        }
    }
    ~ScopedBytes() {
        if (mByteArray != NULL) {
            mEnv->ReleaseByteArrayElements(mByteArray, mPtr, readOnly ? JNI_ABORT : 0);
        }
    }
private:
    JNIEnv* mEnv;
    jobject mObject;
    jbyteArray mByteArray;
protected:
    jbyte* mPtr;
private:
    // Disallow copy and assignment.
    ScopedBytes(const ScopedBytes&);
    void operator=(const ScopedBytes&);
};
class ScopedBytesRO : public **ScopedBytes<true>** {
public:
    ScopedBytesRO(JNIEnv* env, jobject object) : **ScopedBytes<true>**(env, object) {}
    const jbyte* get() const {
        return mPtr;
    }
};
class ScopedBytesRW : public ScopedBytes<false> {
public:
    ScopedBytesRW(JNIEnv* env, jobject object) : **ScopedBytes<false>**(env, object) {}
    jbyte* get() {
        return mPtr;
    }
};
#endif  // SCOPED_BYTES_H_included
```

Comment: You should read about templates in c++. `<false>` and `<true>` are template parameters. The template is evaluated on compile time.

Comment: Read the base class, you included it in your question. It's a template class, taking one bool argument (`readOnly`). `ScopedBytes<true>` means you're using the `ScopedBytes` template instantiated with `readOnly` set to `true` at compile time.

Comment: @ThomasSablik To be correct, `false` and `true` are actually _template arguments_ here. Template parameter is `bool readOnly`.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely

Comment: @ Useless，@ThomasSablik，@ Daniel Langr，thank you for your answer sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScopedBytes is a templated class with 2 states: readonly (`true`) or not-readony (`false`).

**When object gets destructed**, if it is readonly it sets the flag `JNI_ABORT` so the memory doesnt get released. If not, the flag is `0` (no value) and the memory gets released.

```
template<bool readOnly>
class ScopedBytes
{
    ...

    ~ScopedBytes() {
        mEnv->ReleaseByteArrayElements(... , readOnly ? JNI_ABORT : 0);
    }
}
```